# Can I substitute chocolate chips for cacao nibs in a cookie recipe?

Tags: substitutions, chocolate, cookies

I found a recipe for Chocolate Brownie Cookies and am wondering whether I can substitute semi-sweet chocolate chips for the 3 TB cacao nibs? I'm going to be serving this at a party so I don't want a bitter taste.

[**Chocolate Brownie Cookies Recipe**](https://www.bonappetit.com/recipe/chocolate-brownie-cookies)
3 cups gluten-free powdered sugar
¾ cup unsweetened cocoa powder
1 teaspoon kosher salt
2 large egg whites
1 large egg
4 oz. bittersweet chocolate, chopped
3 tablespoons cocoa nibs

I saw that this question was asked previously but the answers all assumed that the bitter taste of the nibs was preferred. I tried to post a comment but don't have 50 points!

Comment: I was curious about the gluten-free powdered sugar.  I thought all powdered sugar was gluten free.  But, I looked it up, and apparently there are a few brands that include some wheat products in the blend.  Thanks for helping me learn something new!

Answer (score 4):

You can.

It will be a different cookie, but chocolate chips are conventional in chocolate cookies -- more so than cocoa nibs in fact.  I assume they're simply stirred in to the mix after the other ingredients.  The texture of the surrounding cookie (and the cooking time) may be affected a little, but only within normal batch-to-batch variation.

If the bittersweet chocolate is added in the same way (as opposed to melted), I'd just scale that up. You may instead want to use a contrasting chocolate.  You could even replace the nibs with chopped nuts.

Comment: Yes, the bittersweet chocolate is folded in along with the cacao nibs.

Comment: I really like the idea of using nuts or a contrasting chocolate.  Milk chocolate chips would go really well with the bittersweet chocolate, and it would reduce the overall bitterness of the cookies.  Keep in mind that you should increase the amount significantly.  (3 tablespoons of chocolate chips won't do much for your cookies.)

Comment: @mrog the increase is a good point.  I was tempted to suggest white chocolate for the visual effect, but it burns so easily it would need extra carer

Comment: @ChrisH You're right about the visual effect of white chocolate.  That would also be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely you can as long as they're not being melted into the dough. Cocoa nibs are smaller than chocolate chips, if you use chips you'll run into bigger chunks of chocolate. Cocoa nibs are also a slightly different flavor, more complexity and less powerful chocolate flavor, so you'll get a different result.

If you don't have cocoa nibs but you want to replicate the consistency and shape you could shave some chocolate on a grater, or chop it into small chunks with a knife.

Comment: Some brands also offer mini-chocolate chips... that's what I usually use since I make smaller cookies. :D